# AngularJS: Unknown provider: recipeNameProvider <- recipeName

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller, provider

I'm trying to write my first service and I want to create service for popups. But I have problems with passing controller. Here it is:

```
'use strict';

class bobVotingPopupController {
    constructor($scope, $element) {
        console.debug(123);
    }
}

bobVotingPopupController.$inject = ['$scope', '$element'];

export default angular
    .module('bob.voting.popup.controller', [])
    .controller('bobVotingPopupController', bobVotingPopupController);
```

I'm calling my service and passing controller by require and filename:

```
modalService.open({
            template: 'modal.bob.voting.html',
            controller: require('./bob.voting.popup.controller')
        });
```

After that I want to render my popup and add my controller:

```
scope.popupTemplate = angular.element(require(`./views/${params.template}`));
scope.popupController = params.controller;
element.find('.popup__body').append(scope.popupTemplate);
$compile(scope.popupTemplate)(scope);
$controller(scope.popupController.controller, {$scope: scope.popupController.$scope}, {});
```

And at the last line I getting error:

```
Unknown provider: recipeNameProvider <- recipeName
```

I found that providers only as arguments for my controller:

```
controller:(recipeName, factoryFunction)
```

What I should to do?